# If a Select All option is Checked then display a div using bootstrap multiselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

After Selecting "Select All" option in the drop down list,I'll click on a generate graph button.Then I want to display a chart containing of all options in the drop down list in a particular div using  bootstrap multi-select.

My code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title>jQuery Multi Select Dropdown with Checkboxes</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-3.1.1.min.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" type="text/css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-2.3.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="PiDiv"></div>
<div id="AllDiv"></div>
<form id="form1">
  <div style="padding:20px">
    <label>Select Country</label>
    <select id="selectId" multiple="multiple">
      <option value="India">India</option>
      <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
      <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
      <option value="Nepal">Nepal</option>
      <option value="Iraq">Iraq</option>
      <option value="China">China</option>
    </select><br /><br />
    <input type="button" id="btnget" value="Get Selected Values" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
        $('#selectId').multiselect({
          includeSelectAllOption: true
        });
        $('#btnget').click(function() {
          alert($('#selectId').val());
          if($('#selectId').val() == "India"){
            $("#PiDiv").load("/home/divya/html_docs/pi.html");
          }
        })
      });
    </script>
  </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm able to select one option and display its corresponding chart.But for select all option,I'm not getting how to display a div after clicking on a generate graph button.Can anyone please suggest me on this issue ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this option. Change the html to below and replace your URL in `data-url`

```
<select id="selectId" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="India" data-url="<!-- URL -->">India</option>
    <option value="Japan" data-url="<!-- URL -->">Japan</option>
    <option value="Germany" data-url="<!-- URL -->">Germany</option>
    <option value="Nepal" data-url="<!-- URL -->">Nepal</option>
    <option value="Iraq" data-url="<!-- URL -->">Iraq</option>
    <option value="China" data-url="<!-- URL -->">China</option>
</select>
```

jQuery Code

```
$('#btnget').click(function() {
    $("#PiDiv").empty();
    $('#selectId option:selected').each(function(index,elem){
        if(typeof $(elem).data('url') != "undefined"){
            $.get( $(elem).data('url'), function( data ) {
                $("#PiDiv").append(data);
            });
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: Actually,here in my code I didn't mentioned Select All option exclusively with an id  attribute.I've just mentioned   "includeSelectAllOption: true" this line,so that bootstrap multiselect will take care of adding Select All option in the drop downlist.Then without id ,how can I display a div ?

Comment: basically the plugin hides your selectbox and creates a fake dropdown using css and js. So that select all option is NEVER added to the selectbox (so it doesnt need any ID info).

Comment: By using the above code,I got a select All option in the drop down box.If I check the select All option,it is checking all the other options in the drop down box.I can do like this ,but it have very lengthy options i.e, nearly it may have 180 countries.                                                                          if($('#selectId').val() == "India","Japan","Germany","Nepal","Iraq","China"){
            $("#AllDiv").load("/home/divya/html_docs/all.html");
          }

Comment: since you have enabled multiple option i am getting all the selected options and looping tru it and loading the content based on the data-url. If you are using `$('#selectId').val()`, you will get array of selected value strings.

Comment: K fine den .Thanks a lot for ur suggestion.